# .each(function() for div heights

Tags: jquery

I have some div.rows on a page, each row has a div containing an image and a div containing text. I have some jquery working to apply the height of the text div to the image div, so they're both the same height.

However that first text div height currently gets applied to all image divs on the page, and I want the height calculated based on the text div in each row.
I've found references to the .each(function() but obviously don't have it set correctly - any suggestions?

jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/iain_g/tw1ce03f/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('div.row').each(function() {
    jQuery('div.feature-image').css('height', jQuery('div.feature-text').outerHeight() + 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.feature-image,
.feature-text {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.feature-text {
  background: #999;
}

.feature-image {
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="feature-image"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300"></div>
  <div class="feature-text">
    <p>Nam qui sunt estias et faceatias elibea solorem reped et illuptu ritaes asit es pore re voluptature voluptist, veriosam imenecum ut et officae. Itat ipsus mi, ommoluptae.
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>quick clearfix</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="feature-image"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300"></div>
  <div class="feature-text">
    <p>Nam qui sunt estias et faceatias elibea solorem reped et illuptu.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What *should* be the height, the highest of all?

Comment: Do you need to support older browsers? Because this is achievable with flex-box, purely in CSS.

Comment: If you're in the `each()` loop and use selectors like `div.feature-image` and `div.feature-text`, you're selecting all of those items on the page. Instead, you need to reference the current `row` individually. You're likely looking for `$(this).find('div.feature-image')`, which will modify only items within the current `row` instead of every item on the page.

Comment: @Santi - that was it - thank you - if you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct so you get the credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

```
jQuery('div.row').each(function() { 
var textHeight = $(this).find('.feature-text').outerHeight()
$(this).find('img').height(textHeight);
    });
```

Cheers

Comment: my Pleasure (y)